# Integration between js and php code in custom module

Tags: blocks, javascript

I'm writing a custom module which outputs blocks with various deltas. Later, a jQuery code has to be attached for every generated block, aware of their id's, as in `$('#mymodule-block-delta')`. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to pass the data from PHP to JS:

```
$block_ids = array('blockid1', 'blockid2');
$settings = array('myModule' => array('blockIds' => $block_ids));
drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
```

Then in JS you can pick these up like so:

```
var blockIds = Drupal.settings.myModule.blockIds;
```