# How to get drupal module path in javascript?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to use this: `var path = Drupal.settings.mymodule.basePath;`but I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'basePath' of undefined.

Comment: Why would you need it? Maybe there is an other way to get the same effect?

Comment: I have path to images in javascript code that are not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a module is enabled with JavaScript](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112289/check-if-a-module-is-enabled-with-javascript)

Comment: No, javascript is working but images don't.

Comment: I disagree with duplicate mark @AnilSagar posted. On the other hand, some pointers from it might be used to pass arbitrary data from PHP to JS. And even more direct way is [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/27029/16495). This could be used to pass URLs of the images. But it does not answer the question as written, so no duplicate either, just a helpful link.

Comment: I found the answer: `drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('basePath' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'), '')), 'setting');`

I got here the path to my module and just posted it to javascript:

`var path = Drupal.settings.my_module.basePath;`

Comment: @josaric Glad you did. Don't forget to post it as actual answer when possible. Or, if you don't want to wait, I can post it for you as a Community Wiki.

Comment: Ok, you can do it, I'm new on this forum and I can't answer my own question yet. Tnx

Comment: Agree, not a dup.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to call `drupal_add_js()` with a 'settings' parameter. This will inform your Drupal.settings javascript namespace about the settings/variables you need in this file via drupal. Try the following :

Lets suppose you want to call a specific *.js file on a nodes' view page, call it as :

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('basepath' => '<your-drupal-base-path>')), 'setting');
```

This `basepath` is global and you can get it in any *.js file called at this point. Next, you can use this `basepath` in your *.js file as :

```
var path = Drupal.settings.myModule.basepath;
```

Comment: Where should we put this code: `drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('basepath' => '<your-drupal-base-path>')), 'setting');
`
I've put it in *MYMODULE.module* but it returns fatal error: call to undefined function drupal_add_js()

Answer (score 2):

1. It starts with adding the following line to your modules .info file
   (rename MYMODULE to your module name or the name you want to give to
   your javascript file)

   scripts[] = MYMODULE.js
2. The next step is to create the MYMODULE.js file. The general
   template of the javascript file looks like:

   ```
     (function ($) {
        Drupal.behaviors.MYMODULE = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
           // Your javascript code here
       }
     };
   }(jQuery));
   ```
3. You can pass variables from your PHP to your Javascript file by
   adding the following code somewhere in your module.

   drupal_add_js(array('MYMODULE' => array('tax_rate' => '0.06')), 'setting');

You can now access this variable in your JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MYMODULE = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // You can access the variable by using Drupal.settings.MYMODULE.tax_rate
      alert(Drupal.settings.MYMODULE.tax_rate);

    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

At First you need to have a module or create a module

See detailed steps below on adding this condition

- Create a folder called 'custom' in `sites/all/modules`
- Create a folder called 'mycustomjs' in above custom folder
- Create a file called 'mycustomjs.info' inside above folder with

below code

```
name = My Custom JS Alters
description = A custom module to interact with JS
core = 7.x
package = Custom
```

Create a file called mycustomjs.module inside 'mycustomjs' folder with
below code

```
<?php



 function mycustomjs_init(){

      global $base_path;
      global $base_url;

     $my_base_path = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . $GLOBALS['base_path'];
    // or $my_base_path = $base_url . $base_path;


       $my_settings = array(
         'basePath' => $base_path,
         'animationEffect' => variable_get('effect', 'none')
       );

      drupal_add_js(array('mycustomjs' => $my_settings), 'setting');


    }
?>
```

For JS side

```
var basePath = Drupal.settings.mycustomjs.basePath;
var effect = Drupal.settings.mycustomjs.animationEffect;
```

For more information See below

[Creating Drupal 7.x modules](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7)

[Drupal 7 global javascript variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14234901/1877909)

[The Drupal JavaScript API](https://drupal.org/node/304258)

[Drupal Base Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7)

[get-complete-base-url-drupal-site](http://data.agaric.com/get-complete-base-url-drupal-site)

Answer (score 0):

To get the path on js file like following:

```
var path = Drupal.settings.myModule.basepath;
```

First need to initiate add_drupal_js() with 'settings' parameter like :

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('basepath' => '<the-path>')), 'setting');
```

Example:

```
drupal_add_js( array( 
   'myModule' => array(
             'basepath' => drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule')
              )
    ), 'setting' 
);
```

Then on any *.js file you can access this variable as following:

```
 (function ($) {
      Drupal.behaviors.myModule= {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
          // You can access the variable by using var 
          path = Drupal.settings.myModule.basepath;
          console.log(Drupal.settings.myModule.basepath);

        }
      };
    }(jQuery));
```